# Can't include something from folder in root

Tags: php, webserver, filepath

I'm unable to include files in a folder from the root. Here's something similar to what I'm trying to do.

```
Root:
 -folder1
   --folder2 (I need to include stuff in this folder)

 -otherfolder1
   --otherfolder2
     --otherfolder3 (This is my website folder)
```

This is what I have for my path so far which doesn't work.

```
define("FOLDER2_ROOT", "/folder1/folder2/");
```

Comment: `../../../folder1/folder2/`

Comment: Keep in mind that you may not have the necessary right to access a folder outside of your website-root-folder (And if you do, it may be a security risk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **../** is used to go up one folder.

So according to your situation, you need the following code:

```
include("../../../folder1/folder2/abc.php");
```

Comment: I know for sure that this approach gives problems in quite a few situations (to not mention what is associated with using relative paths; for example: `include` in a file which is included in another one). But I have tested it right now with the last stable PHP version in a simplistic case and it works fine, so I will delete my comment (but continue relying on absolute paths for all my includes :)).